# Should I need to deploy .VBproj file

Tags: deployment, continuous-deployment

I have added a class and also a third party DLL (add in references) in my Web project. I need to deploy this change in a new server where same project exist.
Do I need to deploy .VBproj file with my web project DLL and third party DLL?

I am confused because what i know that .VBproj file keep the folder structure. Can I deploy the change without deploying the .VBproj file?

Comment: What is your current continuous deployment process?

Comment: Hi thanks for reply. Old project was developed in VS 2003 with .net framework 2. I convert it to VS 2010 and add those classes. use .net framework 2 to build the new project.